# Formvalidation.io: how to keep the submit button disabled while the form is submitting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, formvalidation.io

In the `success.form.fv` event callback I disable the submit button, but if an input value is changed while the for is still submitting (ajax) the submit button gets enabled.

How to keep the submit button disabled while the form is submitting and not re-enable the submit button if the input value is changed while the form is still submitting?

Comment: if the submission is done using ajax disable the button after call of the submit function and enable it inside the success method

Comment: @brk i do that, if you read the details